# How do I use SQLAlchemy to cascade deletes in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

I've been reading various examples from SQLAlchemy documentation for cascade deletes, but nothing I try seems to work. Below is some sample code adapted from that documentation, but using back_populates instead of backref, as I understand that backref is being deprecated.

In the "**main**" section below, I would expect that deleting the order that "contains" the items would delete the items as well, but that does not happen. Obviously I don't understand something about how to configure these tables... what is it?

```
# third party imports
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists

Base = declarative_base()


class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "business_order"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    items = relationship(
        "Item", back_populates="order", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan"
    )


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "business_item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("business_order.id"))
    order = relationship("Order", back_populates="items")


def get_session(url="sqlite:///:memory:", create_db=True):
    """Get a SQLAlchemy Session instance for input database URL.
    :param url:
      SQLAlchemy URL for database, described here:
        http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#database-urls.
    :param create_db:
      Boolean indicating whether to create database from scratch.
    :returns:
      Sqlalchemy Session instance.
    """
    # Create a sqlite in-memory database engine
    if not database_exists(url):
        if create_db:
            create_database(url)
        else:
            msg = (
                "Database does not exist, will not create without "
                "create_db turned on."
            )
            print(msg)
            return None

    connect_args = {}

    engine = create_engine(url, echo=False, connect_args=connect_args)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # create a session object that we can use to insert and
    # extract information from the database
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
    session = Session()

    return session


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sqlite_url = "sqlite:///test_sqlite.db"
    session = get_session(sqlite_url)
    order = Order(name="order1")
    session.add(order)
    item = Item(order_id=order.id, name="item1")
    session.add(item)
    session.commit()
    session.delete(order)  # should delete items too, right?
    session.commit()
    orders = session.query(Order).all()
    print(len(orders))  # this returns 0 as expected
    items = session.query(Item).all()
    print(len(items))  # this returns 1, why?
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support

Comment: I had not seen that. However, I don't understand how it helps me. I tried amending the end of my get_session() function to look like this: ```if "sqlite" in url:
        engine = session.get_bind()
        connection = engine.connect()
        connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
        connection.close()

    return session``` It doesn't change the behavior of the script.

Answer (score 1):

`Order` has an (implicit) autoincrement PK. When you do

```py
    order = Order(name="order1")
    session.add(order)
```

`order.id` is `None`. Therefore, when you do

```py
   item = Item(order_id=order.id, name="item1")
```

`item.order_id` will also be `None`, so `item` is actually not associated with `order`. Therefore, the delete doesn't cascade.

`order` doesn't get its `id` until `.flush()` (or `.commit()`) is called. So you could either do

```py
    order = Order(name="order1")
    session.add(order)
    session.flush()  # !
    item = Item(order_id=order.id, name="item1")
    session.add(item)
    session.commit()
```

or do

```py
    order = Order(name="order1", items=[Item(name="item1")])
    session.add(order)
    session.commit()
    session.delete(order)  # should delete items too, right?
    session.commit()
    orders = session.query(Order).all()
    print(len(orders))  # this returns 0 as expected
    items = session.query(Item).all()
    print(len(items))  # this also returns 0 as expected
```

Comment: I added a session.flush() in the spot indicated in the first suggestion, and I still see the same behavior. I have one question and one comment: Q: You say Order has an implicit primary key - isn't this "id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)" fairly explicit? Comment: If I examine this file using sqlite, I see no indication that the cascade directives I gave were applied at all. I suspect my problem has to do with the syntax of back_populates.

Comment: What's implicit is the autoincrement behaviour. A single-column Integer primary key without `autoincrement=False` is assumed to be an autoincrement (a.k.a. "identity") column.

Comment: "I suspect my problem has to do with the syntax of back_populates." - No, they're fine. I copied and pasted them exactly and [this code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/3d46b20ea43650267d85ff6ed09d8f3c) works properly.